# Regex Expression to not allow spacing at beginning

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a regex expression that allows A-Z without regard for case and also allow 0-9 but not as the first character and also allow the underscore but not as the first character as well. It should also allow spaces but should not allow only spaces at the beginning or at end. So e.g. the following should be valid:

- "This"
- "This is Valid"
- "This_Is_OK_1"

These should not be valid

- "123"
- "This1    "
- "   This    "

I have the following:

> [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$", ErrorMessage = "The name only
>   allows letters and numbers")]

but this allows spaces at the beginning.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Vince.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex

^[a-zA-Z]+.*?[^\s]$

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/sL8zG3/1) via Regex101. You can also test it there.

It matches the test cases you provided. Hope this helps!

Hogan

Comment: Thank Hogan for the help, this solved my problem. I also really like the regex online tester, its very helpful. If I also wanted to disallow any spaces at all do u know what the expression would be? I know the original question was solved already, was looking as a backup solution in case we decided to not allow this as well.

Comment: Glad to help. without seeing examples of valid vs invalid to test against, its hard to say... I'm guessing the following would work.

Starts with a letter and has no spaces in it.
^[a-zA-Z][^\s]*

Answer (score 2):

You want different rule between the first char to the rest, Use this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$
```

Comment: This one fails on 
"This1 "

Comment: Thank you Roy for responding. This is almost there. It fixes the first character to allow A-Z or a-z but it allows too many spaces at the end. e.g. "abc    " is allowed.